# org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum

Tags: integer, apache-pig

```
stud = load 'D:/Pig/studentdb.txt' USING PigStorage (',') as ( name:chararray, roll_number:int);
result = load 'D:/Pig/resultdb.txt' using PigStorage (',') as (roll_number:int, result:chararray);

join = JOIN stud BY roll_number, result BY roll_number;

pass_student = FILTER join by result == 'pass';
pass_student = FILTER join by result == 'fail';

pass_names = FOREACH pass_student GENERATE name;
fail_names = FOREACH pass_student GENERATE name;
```